# @Fetched Request SwiftUI and Entity in an embed framework

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

I was wondering how to use an  @FetchedRequest property wrapper in a swiftUI view, when the entity is defined in an embed framework. I'am developping two apps sharing data model and I moved one entity in the framework. Trying this :

```
@FetchRequest(
        entity: MyEntity.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \MyEntity.timeStamp, ascending: false),
        ]
    ) var devicePositions: FetchedResults<MyEntity>
```

leads to the error :

```
SwiftUI FetchRequest Error: 'A fetch request must have an entity'
```

I do not have that error when accessing it from the in code context in the framework and if possible I'like to avoid the use of a publisher that makes my view re fetch data from my framework on update.
I fetch them like that :

```
let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<MyEntity>()
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \MyEntity.timeStamp, ascending: false)]
```

where presistentContainer is a computed properties defined like this :

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

```
    let framework = Bundle(identifier: "com.blabla.framework")
    let modelURL = framework!.url(forResource: "fileName", withExtension: "momd")!
    let managedObjectModel =  NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: fileName, managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel!)
        container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
            
            if let err = error{
                fatalError("❌ Loading of store failed:\(err)")
            }
        }
        return container
    }()
```

thanks

Comment: You need to make MyEntity class public in framework so it would be visible in app.

Comment: Hum it seems to be the case. Still got the error after generating the managed objects class I do have :: public class MyEntity: NSManagedObject {}

Comment: You define `framework` as the bundle for the framework, but then use `wimoKitBundle` to get the model file.  Is that a transcription error?  If not, please show how `wimoKitBundle` is defined.

Comment: Oups my bad, I edited the piece of code, I did mean framework and not wimokitbundle. Forgot to rename that one when copy pasting my code.